# IndexedDB InvalidStateError, windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, indexeddb

I'm writing a JavaScript/HTML5 Windows 8 app.  I occasionally get a InvalidStateError when writing to the IndexedDB.  My function is below and it happens on the first line.  Is there a way to ensure that the State is correct?

**newEncryptedInfo is a JSON object with 2 string parameters (for the time being).  It is properly formed.

```
function loadData(evt) {
   var transaction = EncryptedDB.db.transaction("data", "readwrite");
   var encryptStore = transaction.objectStore("data");
   var addResult = encryptStore.add(newEncryptedInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an InvalidStateError when creating a transaction, then the cause is usally because the db connection is closed. Click [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBDatabase-transaction-IDBTransaction-any-storeNames-DOMString-mode) for more info about it.

Comment: The problem seemed to in calling function I did: if(EncryptedDB.db) { EncryptedDB.db.close();}. Don't know why. Switched to if(!EncryptedDB.db) { EncryptedDB.db = evt.target.result;}. Haven't seen issue since.

Comment: locigal :). Glad you found it. Btw if you want a fluent lib on indexeddb with more filter options, try my linq2indexeddb (http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com). And if you look in nugget for the Linq2IndexedDBWin8 package, you will get the windows 8 version of my lib

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN and the WC3 is it because the objectstore has been deleted or removed or not available.

MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=IndexedDB%2FIDBObjectStore

WC3

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBDatabase-transaction-IDBTransaction-any-storeNames-DOMString-mode

I found in most cases the objectstore has not been created yet.